# How to call a PopUp in PhoneStateListener Class in Android?

Tags: java, android

Android Dummy Needs help :)

I am trying to call a popUp window which plays a video whenever a Call is received or Dialed over phone.

By a little surfing and finding over Internet i was able to create the Toast whenever a Call is received or made.

Reference : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-on-And

Secondly was able to create a PopUp also, but now I am unable to call the PopUp whenever a Call is Received or Made.

My MainActivity.java

```
package com.shivamkotwalia.video;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private boolean detectEnabled;
private TextView textViewDetectState;
private Button buttonToggleDetect;
private Button buttonExit;

// private VideoView myVideoView;
// private int position = 0;
// private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
// MediaController mediaControls;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Start PopUp

    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
      btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
          (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
          .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
          popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);


        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          popupWindow.dismiss();
         }});

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
         int orgX, orgY;
         int offsetX, offsetY;

         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           orgX = (int) event.getX();
           orgY = (int) event.getY();
           break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           offsetX = (int)event.getRawX() - orgX;
           offsetY = (int)event.getRawY() - orgY;
           popupWindow.update(offsetX, offsetY, -1, -1, true);
           break;
          }
          return true;
         }});
       }

      });

    // Stop PopUp

    // Calling Detection Process //

    textViewDetectState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDetectState);

    buttonToggleDetect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDetectToggle);
    buttonToggleDetect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setDetectEnabled(!detectEnabled);
        }
    });

    buttonExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
    buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setDetectEnabled(boolean enable) {
    detectEnabled = enable;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallDetectService.class);
    if (enable) {
        // start detect service
        startService(intent);

        buttonToggleDetect.setText("Turn off");
        textViewDetectState.setText("Service Active");
    } else {
        // stop detect service
        stopService(intent);

        buttonToggleDetect.setText("Turn on");
        textViewDetectState.setText("Service Inactive");
    }
}

}
```

My CallHelper.java

```
package com.shivamkotwalia.video;

import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallHelper {

/* Code that we need to run when the Call is received instead of creating a TOAST
public class popUpNew extends Activity{

     protected void onCreate() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
          (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
          .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
          popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);


        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

         //@Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          popupWindow.dismiss();
         }});

        //popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

        popupView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
         int orgX, orgY;
         int offsetX, offsetY;

         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           orgX = (int) event.getX();
           orgY = (int) event.getY();
           break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           offsetX = (int)event.getRawX() - orgX;
           offsetY = (int)event.getRawY() - orgY;
           popupWindow.update(offsetX, offsetY, -1, -1, true);
           break;
          }
          return true;
         }});
     }


}
*/



/**
 * Listener to detect incoming calls.
 */

private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {


    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            // called when someone is ringing to this phone

            Toast.makeText(ctx,
                    "App By Shivam Incoming: " + incomingNumber,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
 */
public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public OutgoingReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        // /called when someone is making a call
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "App By Shivam Outgoing: " + number,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private Context ctx;
private TelephonyManager tm;
private CallStateListener callStateListener;

private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;

    callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
    outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
}

/**
 * Start calls detection.
 */
public void start() {
    tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
}

/**
 * Stop calls detection.
 */
public void stop() {
    tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
}


}
```

IN the above code from line 21 to 67 needs to be called when a Phone Call is made or done ?

PhoneStateListener

Thanks in Advance !!!